# How do I get VM tags added into my output text file

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am getting a list of all snapshots in my VMWare environment and I am formatting the list to get "VM, Name, Created, SizeGB" and I also want to get the vmware server tag information from these VMs as well but I am not sure how to do this.  I wanted to get the tag information and place it under "SizeGB" when the list formats itself.  Is there a way to do this?

Here is my script without the tag info:

```
# Adding PowerCLI Snap-in to use cmdlets to connect to vSphere
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

# Connect to vCenter
Connect-ViServer -server $vCenter -ErrorAction Stop 

# Write header on report
Write-Output "VMWare Snapshot Report for $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy)" |
    Out-File $Log -Append

# Get VM Snapshot Information for all Snapshots and send that information to
# c:\automation\AllSnapshots.txt
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Where-Object {
    $_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
} | Format-List vm, name, created, sizegb | Out-File $Log -Append

# Disconnect from vCenter
Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Adding PowerCLI Snap-in to use cmdlets to connect to vSphere
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

# Connect to vCenter
Connect-ViServer -server $vCenter -ErrorAction Stop 

# Write header on report
Write-Output "VMWare Snapshot Report for $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy)" |
    Out-File $Log -Append

# Get VM Snapshot Information for all Snapshots and send that information to
# c:\automation\AllSnapshots.txt
$output = @()
foreach ($vm in Get-VM) {
   $tags = ((Get-TagAssignment -Entity $vm | select -ExpandProperty Tag).Name -join ", ")
   foreach ($snapshot in $vm | Get-Snapshot | Where-Object { $_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) }) {
       $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{VM = $vm.Name; Name = $snapshot.Name; Created = $snapshot.Created; SizeGB = $snapshot.SizeGB; Tags = $tags}
       $output += $obj
   }
}
$output | Format-List | Out-File $Log -Append

# Disconnect from vCenter
Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: I tried using this and there is no output going to the file

Comment: Do you see any output in console if remove Out-File cmdlet?
This works fine for me with vCenter 5.5 and PowerCLI 6.0.